# Error resolving my dynamic json compared to hardcoded json in ng-options

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, angularjs-ng-options

I have a listbox and I'm binding a list of item from a controller.

```
$scope.AvailableListItems = [
    [{Id:1,SupplierName: 'john.banks'},
    {Id: 2,SupplierName: 'jim.chevy'}, 
    {Id: 3,SupplierName: 'ralph.stocks'}]
];
```

This is hardcoded json. When I try this with below html it is working absolutely fine

```
<select multiple id="availabelist" size="10" style="width:100%" ng-change="OnAvailableChange()" ng-model="SelectedAvailItems" ng-options="i as i.email for i in AvailableListItems[selectFaIndex]| filter:availablequery"></select>
```

But, when I try to generate the same thing dynamically, then its not working at all. Getting a blank list box.
Code is as below.

```
 var getSuppliers = function () {  
            var tempArray = [];
            var lstsuppliers = CRUDService.getApiOutput(getSuppliersApiRoute);
            lstsuppliers.then(
                function (response) {
                    debugger;
                    $scope.supplierList = response.data;
                    for (var i = 0; i < $scope.supplierList.length; i++) {
                        arr = {};
                        arr["Id"] = $scope.supplierList[i].supplierId;
                        arr["SupplierName"] = $scope.supplierList[i].supplierName;
                        tempArray.push(arr);
                    }
                    $scope.AvailableListItems = tempArray;
                    console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.AvailableListItems));
                },
                function (error) {
                    console.log("Error: " + error);
                });
}
```

Please help me find the problem in my code.

[Working Plunk link](https://plnkr.co/edit/0v3PTACCOh1J0kEm6AG5?p=preview)

This is how my response data looks like: Updated based on Claies
[image]

```
[{"Id":1,"SupplierName":"ACECO PRECISION MANUFACTURING"},{"Id":2,"SupplierName":"Pentagon EMS Corporation"},{"Id":3,"SupplierName":"QUANTUMCLEAN"},{"Id":4,"SupplierName":"MODERN CERAMICS"},{"Id":5,"SupplierName":"NXEDGE INC"}]
```

Comment: How the response data looks?

Comment: the link you provided doesn't show the broken code at all.  It seems like the problem is with the response, which you could easily verify with a few `console.log()` statements.

Comment: @Claies I have added the screenshot of the response data. Check if that helps. I have connected to .NET core API and I'm getting response in this format. Is there any problem with response? for me it looks normal. But my list box is not getting populated.

Comment: The link i have provided is working link. Its working absolutely fine. But i face problem only if i make it dynamic.

Comment: there isn't anything obviously wrong with the logic in the code you provided;  all I would do if I were troubleshooting the problem would be to log out the value of `arr` in each iteration of the loop, and log out `tempArray` after the loop to see that it is actually holding the expected values.

Comment: The response data is added to the quesion

Comment: Can you write the whole function.

Comment: @Tomas Whole function added

Comment: Everything looks good. If you add `console.log($scope.supplierList[i].supplierId)` to for loop, is everything ok?

Comment: Yes it is. I'm not able to figure out why it doesn't consider as array.

Comment: I did console. Log and got the response and that looks like good for me. Such a strange behavior. Breaking my head from 3 hrs...

Comment: Try `function (response) { var tempArray = [] ...`

Comment: I have done that. It's on line no.2

Comment: But try to move to the line no.6

Comment: no hope. Still same

Comment: If you write only `arr["Id"] = $scope.supplierList[1].supplierId;
                        arr["SupplierName"] = $scope.supplierList[1].supplierName;
                        tempArray.push(arr);` without for loop, is it OK?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After breaking for hours together, finally found the solution.
I have put both hardcoded and dynamic values together to console. and i found below difference.
[image]

I modified

```
$scope.AvailableListItems = tempArray;
```

to

```
$scope.AvailableListItems.push(tempArray);
```

in line no.14, and it worked.
The output is like this after i changed the code
[image]

Thanks for @Tomas and @Claies specifically.